# miniconda.sh: cannot execute binary file on CircleCI

Tags: linux, bash, anaconda

I'm trying to install miniconda in a Docker image on CircleCI, in the image      `circleci/python:3.8.1-buster`. The relevant part of the `config.yml` file is:

```
        - run:
            name: Setup Miniconda
            command: |
              cd $HOME
              wget "https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh" -O miniconda.sh
              chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh
              lscpu
              source miniconda.sh -b -u
```

It fails at the last step:

```
/bin/bash: line 8: source: miniconda.sh: cannot execute binary file

Exited with code exit status 126
```

Why is this happening? All answers point towards a 32/64 bit issue, but the output of `lscpu` on the machine shows a 64 bit processor:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              36
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-35
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  18
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             3400.068
BogoMIPS:            5999.99
Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            25344K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-35
```

*Edit*: output of `ðf /home/circleci/anaconda.sh` and mount:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay        314572800 687992 313884808   1% /
overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/J5IWZGHJNARUQC7X4CTO4BQ5ES:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/XD3PZDOGNYU2YYHXGHCLNOUVAC:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/CA7AZTLLGSK4OEUHU4BEOEUPIZ:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/DYOXGGA7RXPQHYWEG3ZXBAFKEQ:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/EYCBKX2PUH43IQJCIH23BDYYQS:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/YDXS6RTH4KKHJ4OKCV3SGEQSHF:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/XDZBSFNC2FX7SVQREIWX3OGHVV:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/FE4RM6NUAZK7BQFAECHFBIMSUG:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/7YUOGPPFPIBDQ4M3RBYYYQ4JXV:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/6764TLBVJENFCAR3XG5NA2QFLH:/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/l/6LISH4KPYTHH4LYFAG52BLTJ44,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/21378034c56dca452822d84486f51f01380f9bd9d70a8f383da40faa876bf328/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/21378034c56dca452822d84486f51f01380f9bd9d70a8f383da40faa876bf328/work)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
...
```

Comment: Just an idea: is the `miniconda.sh` file on a filesystem with the `noexec` flag set?

Comment: @mtak can you guide me on how to check that?

Comment: btw a few line above I tried  `echo "echo hello" > test.sh` followed by `bash test.sh` and it worked

Comment: That's not the same unfortunately. With `bash test.sh` you execute bash, and "load in" the script. That's a different way of starting a script than `./test.sh` (and it would be relevant in this context). You can check the mount options with the `mount` command. Find the filesystem this file is on and check if there is `noexec` anywhere on the line.

Comment: It seems it's mounted on overlay and there is no `noexec` on the corresponding line of mount's output.
I am able to run `source ./anaconda.sh -h` to display the help, and also `source ./anaconda.sh`. It's when I use the `-b` option, passed to avoid the script asking me to accept the license, that the issue happens.

Answer (score 0):

From the Anaconda/Miniconda documentation I have seen, you need to call the script with Bash, and not just `source` it. You can still add any arguments that you want for a silent installation.

From the [installation instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/):

```
To run the silent installation of Miniconda for macOS or Linux, specify the -b and -p arguments of the bash installer. The following arguments are supported:

    -b—Batch mode with no PATH modifications to ~/.bashrc. Assumes that you agree to the license agreement. Does not edit the .bashrc or .bash_profile files.
    -p—Installation prefix/path.
    -f—Force installation even if prefix -p already exists.

EXAMPLE:

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
```

Comment: I had tried before, but it was failing too.
Very odd, but in the end I figured out that running `bash miniconda.sh -b -u` was not working, while `bash miniconda.sh -bu` worked.

Comment: @P.Camilleri Please post this as an answer and mark it as such. It will be much easier for people to find in the future.